# Register CLOB fail or no

Tags: java, oracle, clob

Есть такой вопрос. У меня в базе есть пакет с функцией, который возвращает CLOB. И мне нужно зарегистрировать в java clob для возвращаемого значения. Делаю по логике я все правильно. Подскажите как можно просмотреть зарегистрировался ли CLOB?

```
QueryWithResultAsClob = "{ ? = call FindPackage.findkartoteka('child.municid in(''{BA986261-AC49-4F7B-AC0D-8B4A6AFD9364}'',''{FE00E848-55B3-4E7F-8E15-8DB24F132A45}'')',0,1,2,1)}" 

cp30NativeJdbcExtractor = new C3P0NativeJdbcExtractor();
connection = (OracleConnection) cp30NativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeConnection(Session.connection());
OracleCall = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(QueryWithResultAsClob);
OracleCall.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CLOB);
```

Вот параметры функции:

```
function FINDKARTOTEKA
  (
    MunObr IN CLOB, 
    KindFindKartoteka in INT,
    AllOrAny in number,
    ShowArchive in int,
    UserFindLogin in varchar2    
  )return CLOB
```

Так же я залез дальше по исходному коду и в конструкции switch case нет case для размера CLOB типа. Может ли в этом быть проблема так же?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не обращайте внимание на именование переменных. Досталось от прошлого разработчика, пока пытаюсь запустить его код. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исключение не выбрасывается, то параметр зарегистрирован.

По идее в *vanilla JDBC* возвращаемый параметр не может иметь тип `Types.CLOB` и вы должны получить `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`:

> Throws:
>   SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if sqlType is a ARRAY, BLOB, CLOB, DATALINK, JAVA_OBJECT, NCHAR, NCLOB, NVARCHAR, LONGNVARCHAR, REF, ROWID, SQLXML or STRUCT data type and the JDBC driver does not support this data type

Но поскольку вы используете Oracle расширение JDBC то видимо это у вас поддерживается. В любом случае, рекомендовал бы почитать доки вашего JDBC драйвера, особливо в месте про [Ораклевские extension](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraint.htm)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Исключение у меня как раз не выбрасывается - и это значит, что CLOB регистрируется 100%? Я добавил в ответ еще скриншот. Может ли быть в этом проблема, если регистрация CLOB происходит все таки не 100%? И если все таки регистрация проходит каждый раз при вызове метода, то получается ошибка уже в самой функции в пакете в самой базе?

Comment: К сожалению это почти ничего не означает. Надо трассировать, подключите исходники библиотеки и попробуйте пройтись отладчиком. Можно поэкспериментировать с маппингом `CLOB` до `String` - возможностей масса. Постарайтесь расслабиться и получить удовольствие. Простого ответа здесь нет.

Comment: Спасибо. В итоге все таки вы меня натолкнули на мысль, что не прав здесь код в базе, я стал его отлаживать и нашел в нем ошибку, но если бы не вы, так и продолжил бы топтаться на месте!